# Error occur when run RTC page contains add-in control

Tags: dynamics-nav

I was following the walking through of Microsoft on "Creating and Using a RoleTailored Client Control Add-in". All steps are completed , but when I ran the form (customer card), there is an error : "The page contains a control add-in that is not permitted. Contact your system administrator".

do you have any idea?

thx you,
Makara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you've registered the DLL correctly with NAV. The following guides from MSDN describe how to register your DLL;

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983803.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983818.aspx